# Reactjs @ symbol in parameter: item.enclosure.@attributes how to fix, that this is possible?

Tags: reactjs

I have a .map function in my code and Im getting data from a json output but one of the item parameters is: @attribute but I cant have an @ symbol in the parameter so is there any way I can fix this?

I coudn't really find anything about this because I'm not sure what to search for except for @ symbol in parameter.
this is the code I used to get the data:

```
this.state.news.channel.item.map(function (item, i) {
console.log(item.enclosure.@attributes)
```

```
{@attributes: {…}}
@attributes:
length: "0"
type: "image/jpeg"
url: "https://media.nu.nl/m/aoqxps0aijuy_sqr256.jpg/barnier-eu-niet-onder-de-indruk-van-no-deal-brexit-dreigement.jpg"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

So how can I fix that I can have an @ in the parameter and it properly gets the data from the json.

Comment: Try getting the value as - item.enclosure['@attributes']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.state.news.channel.item.map(function (item, i) {
    console.log(item.enclosure["@attributes"])
});
```

Comment: please provide a small description about your answer rather than just a try that. you might need to ention that he forgot to close the brackets or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the value of a property
We can retrieve the value of a property using 2 different syntaxes.

```
const car = {
  brand: {
    name: 'Ford'
  },
  color: 'blue',
'the color': 'blue'
}
```

The first is **dot notation**:

```
car.color
```

The second, which is mandatory for properties with invalid names, is to use square brackets:

```
car['the color']
```

or even mixing:

```
car.brand['name']
car['brand'].name
```